# Python Loops and Outputs not working

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
print("Guess the hidden number between 1 and 100")
guess = int(input("Enter your guess:\n")
if guess==67
        print("Correct Well Done")
elif guess<67
        print("Your guess is too low. Try again.")
else guess>67
        print("Your guess is too high. Try again.")
```

I then want it to repeat this everytime the user enters an answer and then when they eventually get it right, it stops.

Comment: Use a boolean flag and a `while` loop. Read the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

A simple while loop can be added to your code.  However note, that hard coding the guess value doesn't produce the most maintainable code.

```
guess = 0
while guess != 67:
    print("Guess the hidden number between 1 and 100")
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess:\n")

    if guess==67:
        print("Correct Well Done")
    elif guess<67:
        print("Your guess is too low. Try again.")
    else guess>67:
        print("Your guess is too high. Try again.")
```

You may want to implement a "found" variable and break out of the loop if found

```
found = false
while found == False:
    print("Guess the hidden number between 1 and 100")
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess:\n")

    if guess==67:
        print("Correct Well Done")
        found = True
    elif guess<67:
        print("Your guess is too low. Try again.")
    else guess>67:
        print("Your guess is too high. Try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Added the colons ":". The reason your code is not working is the missing colons after `if` and `elif`.

```
print("Guess the hidden number between 1 and 100")
guess = int(input("Enter your guess:\n")
if guess==67:
        print("Correct Well Done")
elif guess<67:
        print("Your guess is too low. Try again.")
else guess>67:
        print("Your guess is too high. Try again.")
```